# Protocolo tcp/ip endereço fisicos e logicos?

Tags: ip, redes, mac

Se eu já tenho um endereço fisico (MAC), qual é a utilidade de um endereço lógico (IP)?

**Por que as redes precisam dos dois tipos de endereço para funcionar?**

Answer (score 1):

Essa sua pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, porém seguem algumas curiosidades que talvez possam te ajudar a entender melhor:

**Endereço MAC**

É uma identificação única que cada placa de rede possui, seja ela cabeada ou wireless. O MAC atua na camada de Enlace do modelo OSI e é utilizado por switchs de segunda camada (tradicionais) para entregar os pacotes aos seus destinos.

**Endereço IP**

Identifica um host (computador, roteador, impressora, etc) e atua na camada de rede do modelo OSI. O endereço IP é utilizado por roteadores para encaminhar os pacotes aos seus destinos.

**Por que precisamos dos dois?**

Pois o endereço IP também é responsável por identificar a qual rede os hosts pertencem e essa porção de rede é definida pela máscara de sub rede vinculada ao IP. Já o MAC não conhece nada sobre redes.

**Detalhe Importante**

Conforme um pacote trafega pela rede, os endereços IP de origem e destino são sempre os mesmos, porém os endereços MAC de origem e destino são constantemente modificados e indicam qual foi o último equipamento pelo qual o pacote passou e qual será o próximo que ele vai passar.

Em resumo o IP é utilizado para guiar as informações de uma rede para outra e o MAC para guiar as informações de um equipamento até outro diretamente conectado (mesma rede).